# Finding a common prefix/suffix in a list/tuple of strings

Tags: python, strings, python-3.x

The question that sparked this question, was one on Stack Overflow in which the OP was looking for a way to find a common prefix among file names( a list of strings). While an answer was given that said to use something from the `os` library, I began to wonder how one might implement a `common_prefix` function.

I deiced to try my hand at finding out, and along with creating a `common_prefix` function, I also created a `common_suffix` function. After verifying that the functions worked, I deiced to go the extra mile; I documented my functions and made them into a package of sorts, as I'm sure they will come in handy later.

But before sealing up the package for good, I deiced I would try to make my code as "Pythonic" as possible, which lead me here.

I made sure to document my code heavily, so I feel confident that I shouldn't have to explain how the functions work, and how to use them:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

def all_same(items: (tuple, list, str)) -> bool:
    '''
    A helper function to test if 
    all items in the given iterable 
    are identical. 

    Arguments:
    item -> the given iterable to be used

    eg.
    >>> all_same([1, 1, 1])
    True
    >>> all_same([1, 1, 2])
    False
    >>> all_same((1, 1, 1))
    True
    >> all_same((1, 1, 2))
    False
    >>> all_same("111")
    True
    >>> all_same("112")
    False
    '''
    return all(item == items[0] for item in items)


def common_prefix(strings: (list, tuple), _min: int=0, _max: int=100) -> str:
    '''
    Given a list or tuple of strings, find the common prefix
    among them. If a common prefix is not found, an empty string
    will be returned.

    Arguments:
    strings -> the string list or tuple to
    be used.

    _min, _max - > If a common prefix is  found, 
    Its length will be tested against the range _min 
    and _max. If its length is not in the range, and
    empty string will be returned, otherwise the prefix
    is returned 

    eg.
    >>> common_prefix(['hello', 'hemp', 'he'])
    'he'
    >>> common_prefix(('foobar', 'foobaz', 'foobam'))
    'foo'
    >>> common_prefix(['foobar', 'foobaz', 'doobam'])
    ''
    '''
    prefix = ""
    for tup in zip_longest(*strings):
        if all_same(tup):
            prefix += tup[0]
        else:
            if _min <= len(prefix) <= _max:
                return prefix
            else:
                return ''


def common_suffix(strings: (list, tuple), _min: int=0, _max: int=100) -> str:
    '''
    Given a list or tuple of strings, find the common suffix
    among them. If a common suffix is not found, an empty string
    will be returned.

    Arguments:
    strings -> the string list or tuple to
    be used.

    _min, _max - > If a common suffix is  found, 
    Its length will be tested against the range _min 
    and _max. If its length is not in the range, and
    empty string will be returned, otherwise the suffix
    is returned 

    eg.
    >>> common_suffix([rhyme', 'time', 'mime'])
    'me'
    >>> common_suffix(('boo', 'foo', 'goo'))
    'oo'
    >>> common_suffix(['boo', 'foo', 'goz'])
    ''
    '''
    suffix = ""
    strings = [string[::-1] for string in strings]
    for tup in zip_longest(*strings):
        if all_same(tup):
            suffix += tup[0]
        else:
            if _min <= len(suffix) <= _max:
                return suffix[::-1]
            else:
                return ''
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`common_suffix` can be written as `return common_prefix(string[::-1])[::-1]` because the operations are just the simmetric of one another, and this way will prevent duplication.

Also I think you should not handle max or min inside the `common_prefix` function because it feels like the function has double responsabilty: finding prefixes + length interval check.

Why are you limiting yourself to strings? Python allows general functions very easily.

Why do you build all the result and then return it? You should `yield` the result item by item:

Why do you write so much yourself? Using the `itertools` module is much more efficient and simple:

```
def common_prefix(its):
    yield from itertools.takewhile(all_equal, zip(*its))
```

PS: `common_suffix` will now need to use `reversed(list` instead of `[::-1]`

Comment: By the way: while I disagree on many aspects of this code, I find the documentation outstanding, and I could review it very fast and easy because of it

Comment: Thanks! As a side note, I was considering using `yield` but I would have had know way of testing my prefix/suffix length which was important to my project.

Comment: @Pythonic After you call the function do `len(list(common_prefix)) in range(min, max)`. It may lose you on efficiency though. If you want to take really short parts of prefixes of really long prefixes you can use `take` to preserve efficiency. (`take` is `islice`)

Comment: Alright, I'll see how that works out.

Comment: @Pythonic Did you implement another version using `islice`? Was `in range` fast enough for you?

Comment: No, never got around to it. But for my needs, `in range` worked fine. _PS. You have a little typo in your implementation of `common_prefix()` ;) arg after kwarg_

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use a type annotation for `all_same(items: (tuple, list, str))`, I suggest declaring `items` to be a [`typing.Sequence`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Sequence).

I don't understand why you want to do `zip_longest()`, when the length of the common prefix is certainly limited by the *shortest* input.  A simple `zip()` should do.